# Shell Script to check if file is of type Unix Executable File

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a Shell Script where user will pass the path to JAVA_HOME as a parameter. I wanted to check whether the JAVA_HOME path is valid or not. So how can I check whether the input path passed is a exe file ( Unix Executable File ) or not ? Suppose if users passed /usr/bin/java - which is valid, if user passes like /usr/bin/test.txt ( some text file )- which is not valid. So how can I check whether the file is of type Unix Executable File ?

I tried with -x , guess that is not the rite check , since it returns true for /usr/bin also !!!

Comment: Post a snippet of your script where you are seeing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command.

```
$ file /usr/bin
/usr/bin: directory
$ file /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/java (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/java (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
$
```

You can just grep the output of `file` for a suitable string, e.g. "executable".

Answer (score 1):

The man page for test is quite clear that just `-x` isn't going to do it

> -x file       True if file exists and is executable.  True indicates only that the execute
>                      flag is on.  If file is a directory, true indicates that file can be searched.

But if you combine this with `-f` and `-r`

> -f file       True if file exists and is a regular file.
>
> -r file       True if file exists and is readable.

you will know if the file has the requisite **properties** to be an executable.

---

There remains the possibility that a user could have set these properties on a non-executable, but that would clearly be a user error.

---

Man page excerpt here taken from the Mac OS 10.5 versions. You may seem something slightly different on other systems (Linux in particular).

Answer (score 0):

Unix "executables" are anything that have the execute attribute set. You cannot rely on this since you can set execute permissions on a pdf document, for example.

Maybe what you ought to use to detect the type of file is the [`file`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) command, instead. It will tell you whether the file is a binary or plain text, for example.